# Displaying only Unique values in a user control containing a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a user control containing a combobox.  All of the combobox's are bound to the directly to the same datatable, The user control is created about 10 times.  My issue is, the user can select the same values from the combobox in the other comboboxes.  So say for example they select 'Test' in the first one, in the second combo, I need 'Test' to not be an available option.  So each combobox can only contain one of the available options.

I know I need to apply logic to the ValueChanged event of the Combo, but not sure how to limit the options based on what is selected.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are they bound directly to the data table, or do you load the data in and apply it to the combos manually? Are you using winforms or WPF?

Comment: They are bound directly to the Datatable, I am using Winforms, Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to grab the data from the datatable manually, build collections from that for each combobox and then drive them that way? You'd have to listen out to changes on each of them and adjust the other's accordingly, it'd be a fair bit of manual work, but you could probably make it generic.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the selected row from data table and bind it to 2nd combobox on first combo box ChangedEvent.

Let's say your data table is dtTable, then

```
Private void RemoveRow()
  {
   for(int i = dtTable.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
   DataRow dr = dtTable.Rows[i];
   if (dr["name"] == comboBox1.Text) // name is the column name
    dr.Delete();
   }
  }
```

Now bind the dtTable to comboBox 2

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you had shared some code in the question. However, here is something quick and dirty that may help. This of course, can be made leaps and bounds better but as I said, it is quick and dirty.

In the control:

```
public partial class ComboBoxControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ComboBoxControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private string _dataBindingFilter;

    public string DataBindingFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataBindingFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _dataBindingFilter)
            {
                _dataBindingFilter = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DataBindingFilter");

            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable DataSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string ValueMember
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ComboBoxControl ChildControl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void BindComboBox()
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBindingFilter))
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = DataSource;
        }
        else
        {
            DataView view = DataSource.AsDataView();
            view.RowFilter = DataBindingFilter;
            comboBox1.DataSource = view;
        }

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = DisplayMember;
        comboBox1.ValueMember = ValueMember;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChildControl != null)
        {
            ChildControl.DataSource = DataSource;
            ChildControl.ValueMember = ValueMember;
            ChildControl.DisplayMember = DisplayMember;
            ChildControl.DataBindingFilter = ChildControl.ValueMember + "<>" + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        BindComboBox();

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

In the form, say you have 2 controls, then:

```
comboBoxControl1.DataSource = table;
comboBoxControl1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBoxControl1.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBoxControl1.BindComboBox();
comboBoxControl1.ChildControl = comboBoxControl2;
```

It is assumed you have a table object with you that has the data.